# jQuery - Trying to dynamically add new elements created out of DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hopefully, I've titled this right I still get confused with my terminology. I'm trying to dynamically add new elements which I used an AJAX request to get and I placed into a div called `<div class="hidden-tags"></div>`.

Whenever a button is clicked, it triggers this function

```
$(".tags").on("click", '.tag i', function() {
    var lastTag = $(".tags > span").last().text();
    $(".tags").append($(".tagname-"+lastTag).parent().next());
});
```

So it should be appending the `.tagname-VARIABLE` parent's next parent to the `.tags`element but instead nothing happens and there is no element added, nor an error in the console

when i do some testing i found that everything up to the `$(".tags").append($(".tagname-"+lastTag).parent().next());` worked fine, some reason the .parent().next() didnt work; still unsure why

**Example:**
On one of the tests, I did the `lastTag` variable was defined as `portal` so therefore the function is `$(".tags").append($(".tagname-portal").parent().next());`

so it should append the `<span class="tag">guide<i class="fa fa-times tagname-guide"></i></span>` to the `.tags` element but instead doesn't do that and leaves me with no error in the console

Here are the tag layouts in case this helps (just examples)

```
<div class="tags">
    <span class="tag">games<i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
    <span class="tag">guides<i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
</div>

<div class="hidden-tags">
    <span class="tag">games<i class="fa fa-times tagname-games"></i></span>
    <span class="tag">guides<i class="fa fa-times tagname-guides"></i></span>
    <span class="tag">video<i class="fa fa-times tagname-video"></i></span>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

**To clarify, what i'm trying to do:**
I've used AJAX to get a response in JSON and used `$.each($.parseJSON(response), function(k, v) {` to split the keys and values, i've then used a function which cuts the array off after a certain total character count, i then want to be able to find the next key/value after that 'cut off point' with jquery/js, and then the next key/value etc etc

```
if (tagchars < 415) {
    $(".tags").append("<span class='tag'>"+k+"<i class='fa fa-times'></i></span>");
    $("table").append("<tr><td>"+k+"</td><td>"+(v*2)+"%</td></tr>");
}
```

the json looks something like `{"tagname":"value", "tagname":"value"},`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], my head is spinning, too many things happening o_o

Comment: "Head spinning" was *exactly* the term I was going to use too!

Comment: I've just added a few words, everything before the example is what my problem is, the rest is just extra and edit isn't needed, just what i'm trying to accomplish if that helps anybody

Comment: here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/manoeuvres/t7myt5yk/2/ i found that it works, but only once, because once the tag is removed from 'hidden-tags' it brakes the sequence. so I've added `.clone()` to copy it and enable the sketch to continue. Not actually sure if it helps?